# Spring @Scheduled cron job

Tags: spring, cron, spring-scheduled

I am looking to fire off a task everyday at 9am. I am getting some funky results. Currently my job looks like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 9 * * ?")
```

What is going wrong with this? Is this the correct expression?

Comment: What are those **funky results**.

Comment: @M.Deinum mainly, my intended result is not happening. I switched the job around to test it and made it "0 31 * * * ?" 2 minutes prior to when it should fire off and it seemed to go with intended results. this leads me to believe it must be something with my current syntax for 9am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe @Scheduled(cron="0 0 9 * * *") should work. Also make sure that you are on right time zone. Have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQiCjQkM06U&t=1s) to know different possible ways to use cron expression with @Scheduled.

Comment: This fixed it for me. My EC2 instance was configured to a different time.